# Open Status settings page

Tags: android, android-activity, settings, status

Does anyone know how to open the Settings>About Phone>Status activity programmatically?

Thanks![image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create an intent, set classname/classpath using bellow values and start intent

Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.android.settings/.deviceinfo.Status }

Comment: i didn't understand, could you add more explain please?

Answer (score 1):

By using **adb logcat ActivityManager:V *:S** this command I got activity name like **com.android.settings/.Settings$StatusActivity** .Then I created an Intent.

`Intent statusIntent = new Intent();
statusIntent.setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");
statusIntent.setClassName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.Settings$StatusActivity");
startActivity(statusIntent);`